# Values overlap on linechart in p:chart

Tags: primefaces, jqplot

I'm working on a project which compares 2 values of linechart in primefaces. When the chart loads after runing values overlap on chart if the values are closed. How can I solve this problem?

[Here is part of linechart which values overlap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHsEa.jpg)

Comment: Check if the same thing happens with plain jqplot (that is what PF is based on)

Comment: if i use jqplot all pf methots dont work correctly. also i dont have enough experience for writing basic jqplot. i have to find a solution with pf. thanks.